# MVC Razor render HTML on each iteration of a foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach, html-helper

I am rendering HTML with a foreach loop, like below :

```
@foreach (var item in list)
 {
     // some html
 }
```

But it seems that it is iterating the whole loop before starting to render the HTML. I would like to display (render) the html one by one (i.e. if loop iterates 100 times, then it should be render/display the HTML one by one to 100).

Note : To verify that it starts to render the HTML when the loop ends, I did put a `thread.sleep(100)` inside the loop

```
@foreach (var item in list)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         // some html
     }
```

and if it takes `10 mseconds` to start rendering the HTML without `sleep` then after putting `thread.sleep` it takes `1000 mseconds` before starting to render HTML.

Any suggestion as to what I should do so that the UI doesn't get frozen until the loop completes? It should render the HTML as each iteration completes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this inside of a Razor view, then all your HTML will be rendered on the server **BEFORE** it is sent down to the client.

If you want to render something one by one, then you will have to do that on the client via JavaScript.

Comment: i noticed on most of the sites the content starts render when a page opens and it keeps loading and further rendering the records/content, What about those ?

Comment: Is there no server side scripting or any way that it could render records one by one ?